# Wanting to keep local copy of a git branch up to date

Tags: git, github

So I have been following a git build of someones and I made a clone of it to my local machine. Now, I am trying to set up a scheduled task to pull down any updates that could happen in the near future.

This is not my code but someone else's. I don't want to update his, I just want to pull down whatever changes he makes on a daily basis.

What is the best way to go about this?

So far, I set up a local copy using the clone option and specified a specific branch. Doing a branch -r shows the correct branch I want to work with.

However, whenever I try to do a git pull, it tells me the following:

```
Updating 7ff614f..6473b3a
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
        autoProcess/nzbToMediaEnv.py
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.
Aborting
```

Now I have tried just about every command option of pull I can find not, to mention the commit and stash commands as well.

Why does this seem so hard? I feel like I am missing something.

Comment: Git says that you have uncommitted files. Do commit them and *then* do git pull. You also may be more specific about what commands you tried and what results you've got from them. Otherwise it's hard to give specific advice.

Answer (score 1):

If you've made changes to autoProcess/nzbToMediaEnv.py that you want, then commit them with:

```
$ git add autoProcess/nzbToMediaEnv.py
```

or more simply (if it's the only file changed):

```
$ git add --update .
```

Then commit:

```
$ git commit -m'Whatever you did to nzbToMediaEnv.py'
```

Now if `git status` doesn't show anymore modified files you can `git pull`.

If, instead, you don't care about any changes to that file, then just reset hard to where you are (WARNING: this will get rid of any local changes permanently), then pull to your clean working tree:

```
$ git reset --hard
$ git pull
```

Comment: I tried the reset --hard as i don't have any local changes that i want to keep i just want to be able to stay up to date. However here is the result of those two commands. Updating 7ff614f..a299af5
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.
Aborting

Comment: Again the repository has a sample config file and doesn't even contain the real config file so i would never worry about any local changes being overwritten.

Comment: Well, if you don't care about local things, you can try `git pull --force` and see if that overwrites things locally and gets you properly synced up.